# change drupal 7 cck body title

Tags: drupal-7, cck

how to change drupal 7 cck body title in form alter 
for eg:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == "mymodule_node_form"){
   $form['title']['#title'] = t('Event Name');
 }
}
```

i changed title of Title in this way but i couldn't change body title help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to write code in order to modify the Body title in Drupal 7.

If you edit the `Body` field in your content type (at path `admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/fields`), you should be able to change the label from "Body" to another label/title you want.